# Angular 2 video player

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am new Angular 2 and I am trying to build a video playlist. I am displaying my favorite videos in a table format and when I click on a row I want to play a video. Right now I am passing the video class of youtube links on click

```
export class PlaylistComponent {
    onSelect(vid:Video){
    //play video
    };
}
```

The video object has

```
export class Video{
    id:number;
    title:string;
    videoCode:string;
    desc:string;

    constructor(id:number,title:string, videoCode:string,desc:string){
            this.id = id;
            this.title = title;
            this.videoCode = videoCode;
            this.desc = desc;
        }
    }
```

I have the video code on click. I want to use something like:

```
<body>

<iframe width="420" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
</iframe>

</body>
```

How do I bind this to the click event?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using angular 2 I would recommend using html5 video elements over iframe, angular 2 requires html5 anyways.

To bind to a click event you can use angular template bindings.

```
<div>
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let video of videos" (click)="onSelect(video)>
    {{video.title}}
  </div>
</div>
```

To later than select a video you can do something like this with the onSelect method

```
public onSelect(video: Video): void {
  this.activeVideoUrl = video.url;
}
```

Then you hook up the url to video element like this

```
<video>
  <source [src]="activeVideoUrl"></source>
</video>
```